# javascript split and url encoding

Tags: javascript

I have a string of a url:

```
var url = "/_imgs/media/image/Picture%201.png"
```

When I try to split it lke:

```
var path = url.split('image/');
console.log(path);
```

gives:

```
["/_imgs/media/", "Picture%201.png"]
```

ok fine, but when I do

```
console.log(path[1]);
```

I get:

```
/Picture%png
```

What is happening here?

Comment: That's odd. It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Goes OK for me too in chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Ad/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem with firebug rather than the javascript. Chrome displays the second console log fine, but firebug misses out the %20 (url encoded space).

Interestingly, if you try:

```
console.log(path[1].indexOf('2'));
```

You get `8`, which is the correct position. So the variable contains the right data, it's just the console showing it wrong.